# Java interceptor reading request body makes the request empty

Tags: java, spring, interceptor

I have written an interceptor using spring that reads the request body from the HTTPServletRequest, in preHandle method. Request body contains json. I am able to read the request body also but something is happening to the request object and the request body is getting blank. And beause of this the request is  becoming a bad request. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The body can only be read once as soon as it is read you cannot read it again. Why do you read it inside an interceptor inside the `preHandle` method?

Comment: if you would look a bit more hard, you might find that there is already an interceptor which will log requests and responses.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used either JEE interceptors or Spring interceptors and don't know how they work.

But it sounds like the easier way would be to go with a filter (as configured from the web.xml). Since filters call each other in a chain, you could easily replace the HttpServletRequest object that is forwarded with a wrapped one (where you provide the body).

This could probably be accomplished by creating a class of your own, extending the [HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) and then override the appropriate methods (getInputStream sounds like the way to go here, yes?).

Your version of getInputStream would then return a ByteArrayInputStream of the body you already read, or whatever you kind of InputStream you feel is appropriate.