# Get the request body from HttpServletRequest in spring interceptor

Tags: java, spring, interceptor

I need to get the body request of an incoming request from an HttpServletRequest inside an interceptor of Spring.

I only need to access the body request, every time a spring endpoint with `@RequestBody` as parameter is called, in order to perform some checks on it (no logging)

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018896/java-interceptor-reading-request-body-makes-the-request-empty) guy may have managed to do that but he did not show his solution. I would like to use only Spring functionalities.

Is correct using the `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` in my case?

EDIT ==================================================

Actually I can get the body response of an endpoint inside an `ResponseBodyAdvice<Object>`. Is there anything similar also before the endpoint's method call?

Comment: You cannot do that in an interceptor. You would need a filter, store the body and make it possible to read the body multiple times. By default you can only read the body once, if you read if from the interceptor your controller would stop functioning.

Comment: Uhm... right, I saw something like that but are filter something external to Spring?

Comment: A `Filter` is part of the Servlet API. With that you can replace/wrap the incoming request and, for instance, read the body multiple times. However do you really need to read the body? What kind of checks do you want/need to do? Why not validate the mapped elements?